# Conditional convergency of complex series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, real-numbers

The Riemann theorem states that rearrangements of conditionally convergent series of real numbers may have each sum from $[-\infty,+\infty]$. Are there any similar theorems about series  of complex numbers?

Comment: If the series of real parts is not absolutely convergent, you can achieve any real part you desire by rearrangement. If the series of imaginary parts is not absolutely convergent, you can achieve any imaginary part. If both, real and imaginary parts, are not absolutely convergent, you still can in general not achieve any combination of real and imaginary parts you might want, only one can arbitrarily prescribed, the other may or may not be determined by that.